# Problemas com Sharedpreferences

Tags: android

Não estou conseguindo salvar o valor obtido rewardItem do meu para ser exibido em um TextView, toda vez que fecho o aplicativo e retorno ao mesmo o valor e 0.
Alguém pode me ajudar com este erro?

Este é o meu código da atividade principal, onde tento salvar.
se for possível corrija ele por mim...

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem)
{
    addCoins(rewardItem.getAmount());
    SharedPreferences sps = getSharedPreferences("save_coins", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sps.edit();
    editor.putInt("my_coins", mCoinCount);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication()
{

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i)
{

}
private void addCoins(int coins) {
    mCoinCount = mCoinCount + coins;

    SharedPreferences spg = getSharedPreferences("save_coins", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int mCoinCount = spg.getInt("my_coins", 0);
    mCoinCountText.setText("Coins: " + mCoinCount);
}
```

}

Comment: Você está carregando o valor no TextView assim que sua activity abre? Pelo seu código parece que você só incrementa o valor assim que uma recompensa é recebida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o valor do `mCoinCount` não é atualizado ao iniciar o App.

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadAmount();
}

/**
 * Método responsável por carregar o valor do SharedPreferences,
 * e atuaizar a variavel mCoinCount
 */
private void loadAmount(){
    SharedPreferences sps = getSharedPreferences("save_coins", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mCoinCount = sps.getInt("my_coins", 0);
    updateView();
}
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem)
{
    addCoins(rewardItem.getAmount());
    updateView();
}
/**
 * Soma o valor informado como parametro ao mCoinCount
 * e salva este valor no SharedPreferences
 * @param coins
 */
private void addCoins(int coins) {
    mCoinCount += coins;
    final SharedPreferences spg = getSharedPreferences("save_coins", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spg.edit();
    editor.putInt("my_coins", mCoinCount);
    editor.commit();
}
/**
 * Atualiza o valor da tela
 */
private void updateView(){
    mCoinCountText.setText("Coins: " + mCoinCount);
}
```

Comment: Thiago deu certo, obrigado cara.